# Send me a copy via joomla php mail

Tags: joomla

I am building a site where there are several entries, and a contact form extension that works on the basis of Joomla's php mailer. This form can be used to contact the entry owner, but I also need to be able to send an copy to my own address.
I have found out that the code to change in joomla core is:

```
// Add recipients
        if ($bcc) {
            $mailer->addBCC($rows);
            $mailer->addRecipient($app->getCfg('mailfrom'));
        } else {
            $mailer->addRecipient($rows);
        }
```

I just don't understand how.

Comment: Fair enough...now onto your code.  What you've supplied is the core joomla mailer - in other words, if you change anything here, it will affect every email that the site sends for anything at all.  Is this what you want?  If not, you should post some code from whatever it is that you want to include your email address with when sending, presumably something from the "contact form extension" that you reference.

Comment: You are right, that is not what I want. I will be looking at the extension to see if I can find out anything. Thanks. Jelmar

Comment: Its contactform for SobiPro. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/sobipro-extensions/19380 I thought it best now to just contact the developer. Will post here what I find out from him.